# How to make PRAGMA option to be permanent for sqlite3

Tags: sqlite, cygwin, default

I have cygwin version of `sqlite3` which has issue of non-existent temporary directory so I have to set the option either in the prompt or the query file:

```
PRAGMA temp_store = MEMORY;
```

or

```
PRAGMA temp_store_directory = ~/;
```

but I was wondering if there is an option to set the `PRAGMA` to be permanent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PRAGMA temp_store` affects only the current connection.

The only way to change this setting permanently would be to recompile SQLite with another value of the [SQLITE_TEMP_STORE option](http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#temp_store).